# Is there a way to abruptly end a program at the end of a function in C?

Tags: c

I have a school project that requires me to create a C program that includes password protection. I have a function handling logins but when a wrong password is entered the function still allows the user to continue through to the main section of the program. I tried using abort and exit but they don't help. It seems like they just exit the function instead of the program.

Here is my code.

```
    void userlogin(void){
FILE *fp;
char uName[10], pwd[10];int i;char c;

pUser=(struct user *)malloc(sizeof(struct user));

printf("1. Login Through An Existing Account\n2. Create New account\n");
scanf("%d",& i);
//system("cls");
switch(i){
    case 1:
        if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "r+")) == NULL) {
            if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "w+")) == NULL) {
                printf ("Could not open file\n");
                exit ( 1);
            }
        }
        printf("Username: ");
        scanf("%9s",uName);
        printf("Password: ");
        scanf("%9s",pwd);
        while ( fread (pUser, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp) == 1) {
            if( strcmp ( pUser->username, uName) == 0) {
                printf ("Match username\n");
                if( strcmp ( pUser->password, pwd) == 0) {
                    printf ("Match password\n");
                    //accessUser();
                }
                else if ( strcmp ( pUser->username, uName) == 1){
                    printf("INCORRECT PASSWORD\n");
                    printf("ACCESS DENIED");
                    abort();
                }
            }
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        do
        {
            if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "a+")) == NULL) {
                if ( ( fp=fopen("user.dat", "w+")) == NULL) {
                    printf ("Could not open file\n");
                    exit ( 1);
                }
            }
            printf("Choose A Username: ");
            scanf("%9s",pUser->username);
            printf("Choose A Password: ");
            scanf("%9s",pUser->password);
            fwrite (pUser, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
            printf("Add another account? (Y/N): ");
            scanf(" %c",&c);//skip leading whitespace
        }while(c=='Y'||c=='y');
        break;
}
printf("Welcome %s\n", uName);
free ( pUser);//free allocated memory
fclose(fp);
```

}

Comment: `exit` will exit the program, not just the function. Are you sure you are hitting that code path?

Comment: This might be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you want our help then we need an MCVE, together with the actual input and the expected and actual output. And know the contents of your file as well.

Comment: I suspect code should be `strcmp ( pUser->username, uName) == 1` --> `strcmp (...) != 0`

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Yes there is a way - you can call abort or exit...

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/, http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are likely other errors in your code

[`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) causes normal program termination to occur.

[`abort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort) causes abnormal program termination.

If your program is not exiting it is because neither of those functions are being executed.